# In DolphinDB, how to perform moving calculations on rows with equal intervals?

Tags: window, window-functions, dolphindb

I want to calculate the windowed values of even/odd-numbered rows with the `moving` function, how can I achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

Please try `context by rowNo`:

```
select moving(...) from table context by rowNo(<column>) % 2
```

Note: the result table of `context by` won't preserve the order with your original table. You can exec `order by` original rowNo if you want.